Deflate the inflated logo to its original mesh size and position
I want to inflate and then deflate a logo. when I deflate it, I want it to look like in the first frame so it's a perfect loop. But instead when I deflate it looks anywhere near its original mesh. How can I change that? I can't reverse the inflation because it looks clear it reversed and doesn't look good.

Hello, doingorlami, welcome. Can you help us, please,  by describing, or better yet illustrating,  the  exact kind of 'inflation' you're talking about?

Hi Robin, I added a picture. frame 1 is original mesh, frame 90 is inflated mesh. In frame 180 I want it to look like its in the frame 1.

so you just want it to scale down on one axis?

why don't you just render until it inflates and then in vse copy that and click reverse frames?
